# Find exact match of a wikipedia page title using python

Tags: python, wikipedia

I wrote the following code to get a Wikipedia page summary of a string. 
There are 2 problems. First: if the string I am searching for, not having a page in Wikipedia, it brings back the summary for the last string I searched which has a Wikipedia page. Do you know how can I modify it to get the exact match of a page? and if the page is not existed just print me "there is not such a page". Second is that some times it brings me back some pages which have a similar name. I want the exact match of this place with the title of the Wikipedia page.

```
import wikipedia

place= "number 10, switzerland"

if wikipedia.page(place) is None:
    print("no wikipedia page")
else:
    print(wikipedia.summary(place, sentences=2))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import wikipedia

place = "Macedonia (ancient kingdom)"

try:
    if wikipedia.page(place).title != place:
        print("no wikipedia page")
    else:
        print(wikipedia.summary(place, sentences=2))
except:
    print(place + " not found.")
```

You can check the title of the page for an exact match.

Comment: `wikipedia.page` will throw a `wikipedia.exceptions.PageError` if there is no prefix match for the page name.

Comment: @Tgr I’ll add a try/except when I get some time today. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Note: it should be `wikipedia.page(place, auto_suggest=False).title`. Else, errors can occurs, for example try `wikipedia.page("Canada")` and it will throw an error